# Replace A for B, or B for A

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is there a way using `preg_replace` to replace `A` for `B` if `A` is present, or `B` for `A` if `B` is present?

Something like:

```
preg_replace('/ORDER BY field (ASC|DESC)/', 'ORDER BY field (***the alternative not matched***)');
```

to transform any `ORDER BY field ASC` into `ORDER BY field DESC`, and any `ORDER BY field DESC` into `ORDER BY field ASC`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is preg_replace_callback.

Example:

```
function replace_asc_desc($matches)
{
    return 'ORDER BY field ' . ($matches[1] == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');
}

$string = 'ORDER BY field DESC';

echo preg_replace_callback('/ORDER BY field (ASC|DESC)/', 'replace_asc_desc', $string);
```